# MongoDB addToSet in nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm struggling to insert data inside a nested array in MongoDB.
My schema looks like this:

```
 {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c0c55642440311ff0353846"),
        "name" : "Test",
        "email" : "test@gmail.com",
        "username" : "test",
        "password" : "$2a$10$RftzGtgM.DqIiaSvH4LqOO6RnLgQfLY3nk7UIAH4OAvvxo0ZMSaHu",
        "created" : ISODate("2018-12-08T23:36:04.464Z"),
        "classes" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5c0c556e2440311ff0353847"),
                        "cName" : "1A",
                        "student" : [
                                {
                                        "grades" : [ ],
                                        "_id" : ObjectId("5c0c55812440311ff0353848"),
                                        "name" : "StudentName",
                                        "lname" : "StudenteLastName",
                                        "gender" : "M"
                                }
                  insert                   }
        ],
        "__v" : 0
}.
```

What I want to do is inserting a grade for the student inside "grades" array.

Expected result is:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5c0c55642440311ff0353846"),
        "name" : "Test",
        "email" : "test@gmail.com",
        "username" : "test",
        "password" : "$2a$10$RftzGtgM.DqIiaSvH4LqOO6RnLgQfLY3nk7UIAH4OAvvxo0ZMSaHu",
        "created" : ISODate("2018-12-08T23:36:04.464Z"),
        "classes" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5c0c556e2440311ff0353847"),
                        "cName" : "1A",
                        "student" : [
                                {
                                        "grades" : [6],
                                        "_id" : ObjectId("5c0c55812440311ff0353848"),
                                        "name" : "StudentName",
                                        "lname" : "StudenteLastName",
                                        "gender" : "M"
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ],
        "__v" : 0
}.
```

I tried some queries but none of them helped me, even searching a lot.

```
db.teachers.update({"_id": ObjectId("5c0c55642440311ff0353846"), "classes._id": ObjectId("5c0c556e2440311ff0353847"), "classes.student._id": ObjectId("5c0c55812440311ff0353848")},{$addToSet: {"classes.$.student.grades":6}})
```

Basically, I searched for the student with the first curly bracket (if I do "db.teachers.find(the three conditions) the result is correct) and then add to the grades array (of Integer) the value 6. But at this point I get errors, I think I'm making a mistake on the "adding" part.

I need also to do the same thing in Mongoose.
Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Edit: I solved. I post my solution hoping it'll be useful to other:
For pushing inside a triple nested array do:

`db.teachers.update({"_id":ObjectId("5c0c59985ae5981c58937e12"),"classes":{ $elemMatch : { _id : ObjectId("5c0c59a35ae5981c58937e13") }},"classes.student": { $elemMatch : { _id : ObjectId("5c0c59aa5ae5981c58937e14")} }},{$addToSet:{"classes.$.student.0.grades":3}})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/

Try using $elemMatch

```
 "classes":{ $elemMatch : { _id : ObjectId("5c0c556e2440311ff0353847") }},
 "classes.student": { $elemMatch : { _id : ObjectId("5c0c55812440311ff0353848")} }
```